# Any tricks/hacks for exorbitant daycare costs?

Tags: united-states, taxes, tax-deduction, child-care

The **$5000 FSA limit** is a joke given the daycare costs in our area.
Is there any way to use more pre-tax money to pay for daycare ?
Daycare is by far our biggest expense for the year.
Any advice to maximize tax return based on that ?

WA state (no state income tax)

Comment: In addition to your FSA there are: Child Tax Credit, The Child and Dependent Care Tax Credit, and Earned Income Credit that may benefit you.

Comment: As a perhaps too-far-out suggestion, some employers subsidize the cost of child care by providing discounted onsite daycare, which would effectively be a non-taxed benefit.

Comment: If an answer cannot be found for a financial benefit, you may have to turn to a lifestyle/parenting question to find a more economical source of child care. My wife and I recently decided that she leave her employer to focus entirely on our budgeting and child rearing. She's officially the "curator" of our funds. It's been a net financial gain for us.